# I am unable to connect to the Django server with Stomp in Angular

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, django-channels, stomp

I am creating an application that requires the implementation of a real-time messaging and notification system. On the server-side, I am using Django Rest Framework with the Channels library. On the client-side, I am using Angular with the rx-stomp library.

Whenever I try to connect, I receive an error message in the console saying that the connection failed.

Here is my code on the server for consumers.py:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['user'].username
        self.room_name = self.room_name.replace("@", "")
        self.room_group_name = 'room-%s' % self.room_name
        self.channel_name = 'dianazena-ea903e'

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        sender = text_data_json['sender']
        receiver = text_data_json['receiver']

        sender = self.scope['user'].username

        # Save message to database
        await self.save_message(sender, receiver, message)

        # Send message to receiver
        await self.send_private_message(sender, receiver, message)

    async def send_notification(user_id, message):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        await channel_layer.group_send(
            str(user_id),
            {
                'type': 'user_notification',
                'message': message
            }
        )
```

And in Angular:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { API_ENDPOINTS } from '../constants/api-endpoints';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';
import { RxStomp } from '@stomp/rx-stomp';
import { RxStompService } from './rx-stomp.service';
import { Message } from '@stomp/stompjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {

private notificationCount: number = 0;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storageService: 
StorageService, private rxStompService: RxStompService) {
this.rxStompService.configure({
// WebSocket connection URL
heartbeatIncoming: 0,
heartbeatOutgoing: 20000, // send heartbeat every 20 seconds
brokerURL: ws://localhost:8000/ws/notification/1/?token= + 
this.storageService.getToken(),
// Additional options
connectHeaders: {
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.storageService.getToken
}
});


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RxStomp } from '@stomp/rx-stomp';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RxStompService extends RxStomp {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

And output error says:

**client.js:285 WebSocket connection to'ws://localhost:8000/ws/notification/1/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxMTQ5MzEwLCJpYXQiOjE2ODEwNjI5MTAsImp0aSI6ImRmMGJiMDhiZTE5ZDRmZGRiYzlkZWE3YzM0YWIwMmFjIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6Mn0.Fiknf76IzfhPQjl0qhpxdVKzbeXYWD1-Bli3EaRGfyI' failed:**

Am I doing something wrong?
Please help me!